# Eliminating all data over a given percentile

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, percentile

I have a pandas `DataFrame` called `data` with a column called `ms`.  I want to eliminate all the rows where `data.ms` is above the 95% percentile.  For now, I'm doing this:

```
limit = data.ms.describe(90)['95%']
valid_data = data[data['ms'] < limit]
```

which works, but I want to generalize that to any percentile.  What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Use the [`Series.quantile()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.quantile.html) method:

```
In [48]: cols = list('abc')

In [49]: df = DataFrame(randn(10, len(cols)), columns=cols)

In [50]: df.a.quantile(0.95)
Out[50]: 1.5776961953820687
```

To filter out rows of `df` where `df.a` is greater than or equal to the 95th percentile do:

```
In [72]: df[df.a < df.a.quantile(.95)]
Out[72]:
       a      b      c
0 -1.044 -0.247 -1.149
2  0.395  0.591  0.764
3 -0.564 -2.059  0.232
4 -0.707 -0.736 -1.345
5  0.978 -0.099  0.521
6 -0.974  0.272 -0.649
7  1.228  0.619 -0.849
8 -0.170  0.458 -0.515
9  1.465  1.019  0.966
```

Comment: using pandas,If I want compare different col with specific quantile, is there quick method similar numpy broadcasting?

Comment: does it also work when removing over all columns, i.e. `df[df < df.quantile(.95)]`? I expect all the values being filtered out if not in the range and replace by `NaN` if needed.

Comment: Principally the same but more concise: `df.query('a < a.quantile(.95)')`.
If the column name is lengthy that can improve readability:
`col = 'some_verbose_metric_name'; df.query(f'{col} < {col}.quantile(.95)')`

Answer (score 51):

numpy is much faster than Pandas for this kind of things :

```
numpy.percentile(df.a,95) # attention : the percentile is given in percent (5 = 5%)
```

is equivalent but 3 times faster than :

```
df.a.quantile(.95)  # as you already noticed here it is ".95" not "95"
```

so for your code, it gives :

```
df[df.a < np.percentile(df.a,95)]
```

Comment: Can confirm that numpy's implementation is waaay faster if you can afford the column extract cost

Comment: @2diabolos.com is there a way to implement percentile filter on multiple pandas column.

Comment: Something like df[numpy.logical_and(df.a < np.percentile(df.a,95),df.b < np.percentile(df.b,95))] ?
Or you may create a new question for that...

Comment: @deepelement what is the tradeoff with column extract cost?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for a more concise option:

```
df.query('ms < ms.quantile(.95)')
```