# Removing extreme percentiles from pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have a large dataframe (133 col, 10000 rows) that I would like to make jerry-rigged confidence intervals with (many of these columns do not follow a theoretical distribution). Each column corresponds to stocking requirements for a particular component/module.

I would like to just get a min/max of intervals at specified percentiles (for example middle 70%, middle 90%) in a quick manner across this and other dataframes, and am wondering if there is a pre-worked way to do this without iterating through each column in a for loop?

I looked at [Eliminating all data over a given percentile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580461/eliminating-all-data-over-a-given-percentile), but this function only removes above the bounds specified.